# How to query users collection using array of IDs from group collection

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection where I store user groups. Each group has a group name, group limit and an array of users ID's.

I wonder how the best way to retrieve one group details and then users details, like name, photo, etc.

Right now, I am doing two queries to the database. First retrieving the group data(name, etc), second getting a list of users who has in the user details the information of the group ID:

"syncDesp = a4sQ27xb1wuD2rhONU2K"

I'm afraid of calling the database to many times.

```java
// Get Group details
Preferencias prefs = new Preferencias(view.getContext());
listenGroups = pFirestore.collection("syncDesps").document(prefs.getSyncDesp()).addSnapshotListener((documentSnapshot, e) -> {
    if(e != null){
        Log.i("dados erro", Objects.requireNonNull(e).getMessage());
    }
    if(documentSnapshot != null){
        String nomeGrupo = Objects.requireNonNull(documentSnapshot.get("nomeGrupo")).toString();
        textNomeGrupo.setText(nomeGrupo);
        ArrayList membrosGrupo = (ArrayList) Objects.requireNonNull(documentSnapshot.get("syncDesp"));

    }
});

// Get User Details
FirebaseFirestore grupoFire = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
grupoFire.collection("usuarios")
        .whereEqualTo("syncDesp", prefs.getSyncDesp())
        .addSnapshotListener((queryDocumentSnapshots, e1) -> {
            listaUsuarios.clear();
            if(e != null){
                Log.i("dados erro", Objects.requireNonNull(e1).getMessage());
            }
            for(DocumentSnapshot usuarioSnapshot : Objects.requireNonNull(queryDocumentSnapshots).getDocuments()){
                String idU = (usuarioSnapshot.get("id") == null) ? "" : Objects.requireNonNull(usuarioSnapshot.get("id")).toString();
                String nomeUsuario = (usuarioSnapshot.get("nome") == null) ? "" : Objects.requireNonNull(usuarioSnapshot.get("nome")).toString();
                String fotoUsuario = (usuarioSnapshot.get("imgUsuario") == null) ? "" : Objects.requireNonNull(usuarioSnapshot.get("imgUsuario")).toString();

                UsuarioMeuGrupo usuarioMeuGrupo = new UsuarioMeuGrupo();//
                usuarioMeuGrupo.setIdUsuario(idU);
                usuarioMeuGrupo.setNome(nomeUsuario);
                usuarioMeuGrupo.setFoto(fotoUsuario);
                listaUsuarios.add(usuarioMeuGrupo);
            }

            adaptera.setOnItemClickRemoverListener(uMeuGrupo -> {
                Log.i("dados uMeuGrupo Clic", uMeuGrupo.getNome());
            });
            adaptera.notifyDataSetChanged();
        });
```

[image: Group collection]

I wonder if I should query the group collection separately from the users collection or if there is a way of making only one function to retrieve data from both collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to make a single query in Cloud Firestore span multiple collections.  There is no join-like operation like you have in SQL.  The only exception to this is [collection group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query), which doesn't apply to your situation.

What you're doing right now is probably the best you can do with the database structure you have.  If you want fewer queries, you'll have to do something to restructure your data to support that.

Comment: Thank you @Doug already help a lot.
Talking about the database structure would you have any tips on how could I change it?
The user's group is to share data between the user contained in the group. But also need some screen to see, edit the group name and users.

Comment: Since you can only query one collection at a time, you'll have to put all the information into its documents in a way that satisfies the final results you want.